# mqtt.js auto close connection

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have problem with mqtt.js client library.
I am trying to receive messages from emonhub. When I call

```
mosquitto_sub -v -u 'login' -P 'pass' -t 'emon/#'
```

everything is OK. But when I try do that from nodejs:

```
[2016-03-11 10:01:03.771] [INFO] [default] - mqtt connected
[2016-03-11 10:01:07.979] [INFO] [default] - emon/emonpi/power1 0
[2016-03-11 10:01:07.994] [INFO] [default] - mqtt closed
[2016-03-11 10:01:08.002] [INFO] [default] - emon/emonpi/power2 0
(...)
```

This is my code:

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://127.0.0.1:1883', {
    username: 'login',
    password: 'pass'
});

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('mqtt connected');

client.subscribe('emon/emonpi/#');

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        // message is Buffer
        console.log(topic + ' ' + message.toString());
        client.end();
    });
});

client.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('mqtt error: ' + error);
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('mqtt closed');
});

client.on('offline', function() {
    console.log('offline');
});

client.on('reconnect', function() {
    console.log('reconnect');
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You've got `client.end()` in your message handler, as soon as you receive your first message the client is going to exit

```
client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        // message is Buffer
        console.log(topic + ' ' + message.toString());
        client.end();  <---- HERE
    });
});
```